# Session timeout every 5 minutes and I have to loggin again

Tags: session, logging, timeout, jbpm

I have a message regarding timeout session and have to loggin again, losing all not saved work

Hi,
I'm using the jBPM Server distribution, exactly the jBPM 7.74.1.Final server (single zip) distribution and I have install it in my local machine.
The problem its that when I am working into the Business Central interface, making different task over diagrams, objects, instances and so on,  and every 5 minutes I have the next message:
'Invalid response received from server. This probably means that you have been logged out due to inactivity. Do you want to log in again?'
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnALC.png)

and then I have to loggin again because session is expired, in most of cases I losing information and the last modifications are not saved, because jBPM have not autosave in diagrams, configurations and the differents elements.

I have read in other questions something about include the value:

'property name="jboss.as.management.blocking.timeout" value="2400"'

in the 'system-properties' section of the 'standalone.xml' file, but don't works.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have review the question and I have include and screenshoot of the message error to a better description